# How does logstash handle parent child relationships?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is it possible to use logstash to index children documents? The parent child relationship is specified in this elasticsearch help doc [Managing relations inside elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/).

Answer (score -1):

you can send parent id to logstash with _parent field in your json.

and also document_id is used for _id of your document.

check : 
http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch